# User control: Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I cannot get to the bottom of what's causing following error:

```
Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property. 
MenuItem:'WpfApp1.Models.MenuItem' BindingExpression:Path=SelectedMenuItem; 
DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=29578451); target element is 'Menu' (Name=''); target 
property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'MenuItem')
```

It happens when following assignment in view model's command is executed.

```cs
private void OnSelect(MenuItem item)
{
    SelectedMenuItem = item;
}
```

Any thoughts?

**Window.xaml**

```xml
<local:Menu
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}"
    OnSelect="{Binding OnSelectCommand}" Items="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
```

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private MenuItem _selectedMenuItem;
        public MenuItem SelectedMenuItem
        {
            get => _selectedMenuItem;
            set
            {
                _selectedMenuItem = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedMenuItem)));
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public ICommand OnSelectCommand { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MenuItems = new[]
            {
                new MenuItem("Environment"),
                new MenuItem("Versions"),
                new MenuItem("Apps"),
            };
            OnSelectCommand = new CommandHandler<MenuItem>(OnSelect);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private void OnSelect(MenuItem item)
        {
            SelectedMenuItem = item;
        }
    }
```

**Menu.xaml**

```xml
<ItemsControl
        d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DesignViewModel}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                        Command="{Binding OnSelect, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.IsEnabled>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                            <Binding Path="." />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.IsEnabled>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

```cs
  public partial class Menu : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItem",
            typeof(MenuItem),
            typeof(Menu),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Items",
            typeof(IEnumerable<MenuItem>),
            typeof(Menu),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OnSelectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "OnSelect",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(Menu),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectChanged));


        public MenuItem SelectedItem
        {
            get => (MenuItem)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
        }

        public IEnumerable<MenuItem> Items
        {
            get => (IEnumerable<MenuItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }

        public ICommand OnSelect
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(OnSelectProperty);
            set => SetValue(OnSelectProperty, value);
        }

        public static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var menu = dependencyObject as Menu;

            if (menu == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            menu.SetCurrentValue(SelectedItemProperty, eventArgs.NewValue);
        }

        public static void OnSelectChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var menu = dependencyObject as Menu;

            if (menu == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            menu.SetCurrentValue(OnSelectProperty, eventArgs.NewValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post what's encompassing `<local:Menu`.

Comment: I think (but not certain) the issue is that in `Menu.xaml` you're binding to an ancestor of type `UserControl`, which based on what you've shown doesn't seem to be a type in that hierarchy.

Comment: Menu is certainly a UserControl. We need to see its relevant code parts.

Comment: Updated description.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `SelectedItemProperty` used `MenuItem` type from `System.Windows.Controls`, not mine.

The fix.

**Menu.xaml.cs**

```
using MenuItem = WpfApp1.Models.MenuItem;
```